# VBA Deselect all and then Select Values based on list in Slicer

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to deselect all pre-set values in a slicer and then select values based on a list that will be updated on a daily basis. I managed to write the following code but it is running very very slow since my pre-set list was long. Is there a way to make the following run faster?

```
Sub cmdTop10PrioritySlicer()

Dim i As Integer
Dim MemberID As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer1").ClearManualFilter

'Deselect all prior set values
For Each slc In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer1").SlicerItems
    slc.Selected = False
Next slc

'Select values in Slicer based on Top 10 Priority List
For i = 1 To 10
    ID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & 57 + i).Value
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer1").SlicerItems(ID).Selected = True
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: does the sheet that this code runs on have a `worksheet_change` subroutine? in that case disable the `application.enableevents` in the same way you did with the screenupdating. If this is the case that subroutine gets called for every cell you loop through in the foreach loop.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom: uhh not sure what you meant. I wrote this in a module. I added the application.enableevents and it is still running slow.

Comment: I meant if the sheet that you run your code on has that change event in it's own code, didn't think it would fix it but it was an option.

Comment: AFAIK and I could be wrong but you will have to loop through the sliceritems. You could add `Application.Screenupdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlmanual` before you start your code and then reset them back to `True` and `xlautomatic` respectively

Comment: Try This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498126/poor-performance-updating-excel-slicer-selection-using-vba