# Speeding up VBA pivot table filtering

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to figure out why my Pivot table filtering is so very slow, using VBA. The table itself doesn't have too many rows - about 5000 in total. But this slice of code takes about 30 seconds to make the update, and it makes Excel appear to be frozen. I'm using an Array to pass in two values to the filter that I am using. In this case, there are two "People" that I want to select in this filter. What am I missing?
'

```
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each PTItm In PT.PivotFields("Person").PivotItems
        i = i + 1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(PTItm.Caption, myArray, 0)) Then 
            PTItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PTItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PTItm
```

As additional information, I also tried to start by setting Visible = False on all of the items (except for the last Item, since you have to leave at least one Item visible), and then just setting the Visible = True for the Items that I want. But the problem is that just getting through all of the Items and setting to False (snip below) takes the same ~ 30 seconds.

```
With PT
    For jj = 1 To .PivotFields("Person").PivotItems.Count - 1
        .PivotFields("Person").PivotItems(jj).Visible = False
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the loop and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after.

Comment: Yep, I should have mentioned that I tried that already. Sorry about that. Thanks.

Comment: Some things to try here (I know it's about slicers, but still)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498126/poor-performance-updating-excel-slicer-selection-using-vba   Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764504/speed-up-pivot-table-filtering-vba-code